# Using browser back button to return to previous view

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Just looking for a starting point on this problem. I have a view with a weekly calendar, if I click through the calendar, say back 2 weeks, and then click on a link to a new page, I want the back button to take me back to the last week I was viewing. Currently, the back button returns me to the calendar but shows the current week. Is there a way (cookie?) to return to the last viewed week instead of the current week? Or, is using the browser's back button not a viable option?

Answer (score 0):

Check out `old()`.

[See Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/requests#old-input)

Since you didn't provide any code sample I don't know if this may be helpful, I hope it does.